# converting varchar to number and sum gives error:

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, casting

I am trying to sum this column by casting this as numeric, but the values have commas as well which are the source of error on my query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', to_date("date" , 'mm-dd-yyyy')) as day, 
"from merch", 
sum(CAST("amount " AS numeric)) as amount 
FROM tb 
GROUP BY 1,2 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

I am trying to get the sum of amounts for each "from merch" per day.

Error i get is: **Invalid Digit, Value ',', Pos 1, Type: Decimal**

Comment: replace the comma with '' then try.  But why is an amount field not numeric to begin with?  consider casting to decimal with precision/scale

Comment: **Never** store numbers in a `varchar` column. Do you have a chance to fix that broken data model before you proceed?

Comment: How would I do that in the query?

Comment: No I can’t  change the data model - it’s all I have rn.

Comment: Then change the model before proceeding. Storing text instead of actual numbers is a *critical* error. You have no idea what that field contains or how to parse it. Does it contain `1,000.000` or `1.000,000` ? How would you expect to parse either value? If you get this wrong you can end with 1, 1000000, 1000 or an error.

Comment: The reason you got this error (and why it's such a huge problem) is that the text is stored in a format that's not recognized by the server as a number. Most likely, `,` was used as a decimal separator when the server expected a comma, eg `123,45`. If you just remove the comma in `123,45` you'll cover up the error but end up with 12345.

Comment: @vayder What is the format defined for your amount field then?

Comment: In the database it’s varchar(1024) if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: @Vayder No.  I am asking if the fields (masking?) is ###,###,###.00 or #####,00 or something else.   but I think you've responded it's the ###,###,###.00 format.  so replacing the commas work.  but as panagiotisKanavos indicated if you have #####,00 this scenario breaks and returns BAD data and you'll never know.  Numbers as varchar data is not wise.

Comment: No I don’t have values in that format. Thank you for pointing it out though, I’ll look at it anyway.

Comment: @Vayder you probably don't realize just how bad this situation is. That's how you get the 100K electricity bill headlines. If it wasn't for China, one could easily say that most people use `,` as the *decimal* separator. Only China, the US and the countries around the Pacific use `.`. If you process user data the chances are 50% replacement will fail. If the data comes from a web form, the chances are 50% the user and browser will use `,` as a decimal separator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for that valuable information. I don’t have the rights for the data model yet. Where do you think I should start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4cad930d777bfd466a644022cb93e476)

using `replace(string,FromValue,ToValue)`

NOTE: this assumes you have amount in a ###,###.00 format. if not you could return bad data.

```
with tb AS 
(SELECT '1,000.01' as "amount", '01-01-2022' as "date",'z' as "from merch" UNION ALL
SELECT '10,000.02' as "amount", '01-01-2022' as "date",'z' as "from merch" UNION ALL
SELECT '100,000.02' as "amount", '02-01-2022' as "date",'y' as "from merch")

SELECT date_trunc('day', to_date("date" , 'mm-dd-yyyy')) as day, 
"from merch", 
sum(CAST(replace("amount",',','') AS numeric)) as amount 
FROM tb 
GROUP BY 1,2 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[Demo 2 with decimal](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=971d978a0a49017a99add1d00d5cb9e4)

```
sum(CAST(replace("amount",',','') AS decimal(10,2))) as amount
```

This is assuming you've identified the problem correctly.

I (not so recently) found an exchange in comments humorous:

- If you EVER need to do math on it, store it as a number
- If you'll NEVER do math on it store it as string
- If it needs to do both, you need two columns
- Except for dates... store dates as dates period and use date functions on them... not string {shudder} functions!
- and AutoIncrements can be numbers (though we should never do math on them)

@xQbert -- this shall henceforth be referred to as "xQbert's razor"

Comment: What if the actual value is `1000,01`?

Comment: and what if it contains non comma values? and what if it has extra spaces and non display characters.  I agree it's a problem but if it's in the ###,###,###.00 notation described in teh CTE this works.  but it's an assumption

Comment: Which is why the only solution is to *not* use text. Anything else ... actually, that's how you get the headlines `Pensioner got 10K electricity bill`

Comment: I disagree with it being the "ONLY" solution.  already noted: you can lead a horse to water...  If we can guarantee the format of that column then casting becomes possible.  is it fundamentally wrong in today's world yes.  If the application is 30 years old and working you can't change it midstream.  You've already asked if it can be changed the OP comment indicated it could not.  Move on.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanations. Actually, I feel it’s better that I start working on the model. This does solve the problem as the data was ingested in the format your query works for.

Comment: It's best to use the correct data type for data.  You'll have fewer errors in the long run as validation is done on save by the database helping ensure correct data types and values.